# Unicast Communication in Veins

Tags: omnet++, veins

Does Veins support 802.11p unicast communication?

I checked the source code of the class "Mac1609_4" in Veins framework. Referring to the following snippet of the code:

```
WaveShortMessage*  wsm =  dynamic_cast<WaveShortMessage*>(macPkt-> decapsulate());

long dest = macPkt->getDestAddr();

DBG_MAC << "Received frame name= " << macPkt->getName()
        << ", myState=" << " src=" << macPkt->getSrcAddr()
        << " dst=" << macPkt->getDestAddr() << " myAddr="
        << myMacAddress << std::endl;

if (macPkt->getDestAddr() == myMacAddress) {
    DBG_MAC << "Received a data packet addressed to me." << std::endl;
    statsReceivedPackets++;
    sendUp(wsm);
}
```

It seems that the implemented MAC layer can receive unicast packet but I couldn't find any method for sending MAC layer acknowledgements that are required in unicast communication. Any suggestions please?

There is also a [publication](http://www.ccs-labs.org/bib/klingler2015unicast/klingler2015unicast.pdf) by Christoph Sommer et al. that unicast communication is considered harmful in 802.11p. Is it true that because of the reasons mentioned in the paper, Veins framework doesn't support unicast communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veins framework does not support unicast transmissions. In Section IIIC of the publication [here](http://www.ccs-labs.org/bib/klingler2015unicast/klingler2015unicast.pdf) it has been reported that MAC layer of Veins was extended to support unicast transmissions, this means the official release does not include this functionality.

The paper was published in 2015 while the latest release of Veins 4.3 came last month. Since there is nothing mentioned about unicast transmissions in the "Changelog" of the latest release, it implies that unicast transmissions are still not supported.

Answer (score 2):

Recently, in veins 4.7 an experimental implementation is provided. As can be seen on the changelog content in veins website:
*"Add experimental unicast support to IEEE 802.11p"*

To use, you just need to update every message with the *object id* of the receiver on the call of *populateWSM* method (see the method signature for more details):

```
populateWSM(bsm, idReceiver);
```

Additionally, you need to set the *useAcks* parameter of *Mac1609_4* class to *true*.
Just put this additional line on the omnetpp.ini file:

```
*.**.nic.mac1609_4.useAcks = true
```

However is important to note that this implementation does not work with channel switching. When trying to run with channel switching the following error message is thrown:

> Error: Unicast model does not support channel switching -- in module (Mac1609_4)

Best Regards.

Comment: I need to send a message from rsu to a specific car. I set the receiver's address to the car address through populateWSM function. However, the function onWSM of the car node is never called. I tried to change the address to -1 then the function is called without problems. Could you help me with this? I debugged the problem and I am sure that the address is correct. And I did the same settings as in your answer.

Comment: Hi Rehab, 
Did you check if the channel switching is disabled?

Comment: The most simple way to test it is only using BSMs.
To do this, set 'dataOnSch' on the omnetpp.ini file to 'false'
Set the use of service channels to false.
'nic.mac1609_4.useServiceChannel = false'

Comment: Looking the code of MAC layer of veins 4.7 I verified that the address used by the mac layer for unicast methods assumes that the node address is given by: 'myMacAddress = getParentModule()->getParentModule()->getIndex()'; See line 76 of Mac1609_4.cc.

I would like to emphasize that I didn't test this functionality on the time I made my first post. I stopped trying to use unicast when I get the error reported in my answer. (because I needed to use the service channels anyway in my project and the unicast feature of veins does not support it).

Comment: hi Pedro, thanks for your reply. I'm sure that channel switching is disabled. However nothing changed. I used a workaround but I wish I can send a msg to a specific car.